# How to crop a portion from an existing pdf and create a new pdf in java?

Tags: java

I want to crop a portion in sizes like A5, A6 from an existing pdf of size A4 and want to create a new pdf

Comment: I don't have a concrete answer, but you might want  to look at a project called [pdfscissors](https://sites.google.com/site/pdfscissors/) which does exactly this and is written in java.

Comment: I am not looking for a project. I am looking for a piece of code through I achieve cropping a selected area programatically out of a pdf file

Comment: You missunderstood me. That project is written in Java, you can get the code (as it's open source) and check how it's done. You just need to navigate the code and find the relevant snippet.

Comment: I tried my luck with one of such project named Briss which is also written in java, but it had so many other functionalities that I got confused. All I need is a piece of code through which I can edit all the pages of an existing pdf and create a new pdf programatically. I do not ant any user interface.